# Advise on Refactoring a WordPress Multisite

Tags: css, refactoring, wordpress-theming, wordpress

We have a WordPress Multisite with a in-house Bootstrap theme. It's basically a WebPortal for condominiums that allows facility booking with a business directory and a bbPress forum. We are facing the following challenges:

1. We have a small dev team, only myself and another part-time full-stack dev, and a QA/front-end developer. I'm the third lead developer for this product and the first two didn't really do a good job in planning out the product's architecture.
2. We were given the project in a not-so-maintainable way. The markup is incorrect (no `.container`s and `.row`s for the `.col`s), isn't valid HTML, and the CSS doesn't follow best practices (overly-nested, high `!important` usage, usage of `#ids`, etc.).
3. There is a reliance on a third-party plugin for the facilities booking module, but it produces its own markup and CSS that we have to code around to get it to look and feel like the site's base theme.
4. Our `functions.php` is one huge monolithic file with 2.4k lines. When I came aboard, I tried using includes to mitigate it getting more bloated. I don't even know where to start refactoring this.
5. Our base CSS span over 30,000 lines uncompressed and, as mentioned earlier has excessive nesting. We are already using SASS, but even then, most is wrong. I'm not sure if this is normal for a Bootstrap theme. Similarly, I do not know how to start cleaning this up.

While it all works, it's very far from maintainable. We're quickly discovering that implementing new features is a pain. PO finds issues every once in a while across different devices. Plugin updates also cause issues so our development time is even cut more.

I've told our PO that we need to refactor. And while he did agree (mostly because of all the issues he finds), he's also asking if it's the right time to incorporate all these new tech he's hearing like Angular or Laravel.

Are there any advise you can give me to get this product on the right track? How long will refactoring this take? Should we move away from WordPress? If we do, how will we deal with the plugins we're currently using? Any related advise is appreciated.

Here's are production sites in the network in question:

https://sky11.com.sg

https://signaturepark.com.sg